# Openshift Cluster behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, openshift, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have an Openshift cluster in IBM Cloud that is in private endpoint.
In order for us to connect to the master, we decided to use a Reverse Proxy server.

From the reverse proxy, we can curl the https://console.subdomain.domain.com/

But it gives us a 505 Bad Gateway response.

Here is the configuration we use:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://console.subdomain.domain.com/;
    }
}
```

Comment: In OpenShift, when you call the web console. It automatically redirect to authentication URL.

Comment: @hiroyukik I see... does this mean I have to add the authentication URL as well?